# Please help me write regex replace

Tags: php, regex

I've not yet mastered regex, so would appreciate your help with the code.

I need to replace all lines that:

1. start with brackets or parentheses;
2. which may contain either a regular number of up to 3 digits or a combination of up to 3 letters;
3. which may be followed by a period;
4. which digis or the numbers may or may not be inside  or  tags.

Here's the example of what it needs to be replaced with:

```
(1)blahblah => %%(1)|blahblah
(<i>iv</i>.) blahblah => %%(<i>iv</i>.)|blahblah
[b] &nbsp;some stuff => %%[b]|&nbsp;some stuff
```

So the regex will need to recognize if it needs to be applied to the particular string, and if yes, put %% in the beginning of the line, then put the stuff inside the brackets, then put a pipe | (if there is a space between the brackets and the rest of the text, delete the space), and finally place the rest of the line.

So, let's assume I have an array that I'm trying to run through the function that will either process the string (if it matches the criteria), or return it unchanged.

I only need to know how to write the function.

Thanks

Comment: I'm wondering who has mastered `regex`!

Comment: that was a polite way of saying that my knowledge of regex is limited to knowing that it's a powerful way of dealing with strings, but i have no idea how it works :)

Comment: No, I bet my knowledge of `regex` isn't that much greater than yours, for me `regex` is an abis. For a better question it is better if you include examples, ehat you expect and what you tried!

Comment: I'm no regex expert but using an online editor at east helps with some trial and error - http://gskinner.com/RegExr/

It's always worth a quick tutorial refresher too! http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html

Comment: Can the text inside the parentheses contain capital letters, or just lowercase?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is my version.

It uses the fallback regular expression if the first one doesn't match (as agreed upon previously).

**[Demo](http://ideone.com/4GyXR)**

**Code:**

```
<?php
function do_replace($string) {
    $regex = '/^(\((?:<([a-z])>)?(\d{0,3}|[a-z]{1,3})(?:<\/\2>)?(\.)?\)|\[(?:<([a-z])>)?(\d{0,3}|[a-z]{1,3})(?:<\/\2>)?(\.)?\])\s*(.*)/i';
    $result = preg_match($regex, $string);
    if($result) {
        return preg_replace($regex, '%%$1|$8', $string);
    } else {
        $regex = '/^(\d{0,3}|[a-z]{1,3})\.\s*(.+)$/i';
        $result = preg_match($regex, $string);
        if($result) {
            return preg_replace($regex, '%%$1.|$2', $string);
        } else {
            return $string;
        }
    }
}
$strings = array(
    '(1)blahblah',
    '(<i>iv</i>.) blahblah',
    '[b] &nbsp;some stuff',
    '25. blahblah',
    'A. some other stuff. one',
    'blah. some other stuff',
    'text (1) text',
    '2008. blah',
    '[123) <-- mismatch'
);
foreach($strings as $string) echo do_replace($string) . PHP_EOL;
?>
```

**First regular expression expanded:**

```php
$regex = '
    /
        ^(
            \(
                (?:<([a-z])>)?
                (
                    \d{0,3}
                    |
                    [a-z]{1,3}
                )
                (?:<\/\2>)?
                (\.)?
            \)
            |
            \[
                (?:<([a-z])>)?
                (
                    \d{0,3}
                    |
                    [a-z]{1,3}
                )
                (?:<\/\2>)?
                (\.)?
            \]
        )
        \s*
        (.*)
    /ix';
```

Answer (score 3):

```
function my_replace ($str) {
    $expr = '~
        (
            # opening bracket or paren
            (?:\(|\[) 
                 # optional opening tag
                 (?:<([a-z])>)?
                 # either up to 3 digits or up to 3 alphas
                 (?:[a-z]{1,3}|[0-9]{1,3})
                 # optional closing tag
                 (?:</\2>)?
                 # optional dot
                 \.?
             # closing bracket or paren
             (?:\)|])
         )
         # optional whitespace
         \s*
         # grab the rest of the string
         (.+)
    ~ix';
    return preg_replace($expr, '%%$1|$3', $str);
}
```

[See it working](http://codepad.org/V3HT4ajp)

Comment: Note that this function also matches `[123) <-- mismatch`, see http://codepad.org/qVE1ZDBz.

Comment: @ShaquinTrifonoff I know, that's part of what I meant when I posted [this](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/5370127#5370127) but never got as far as explaining what I meant. I just hate to essentially write the same code twice just to deal with that issue. +1 your answer though

Answer (score -2):

```
function replaceString($string){
   return   preg_replace('/^\s*([\{,\[,\(]+?)/', "%%$1", $string);
}
```

Comment: this simply adds %% to anything I feed it